# Is JPath the same as JSONPath in JSON.NET?

Tags: json.net, jsonpath, jpath

Although the names look similar, small changes could be tricky. Unfortunately I cannot find decent info about JPath.

The docs of JSON.NET are talking about JPath and JSONPath and I think there are the same. Am I correct?

> A String that contains a JPath expression.

from [JToken.SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) (see also [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/6b9f467e817854532ea31e6c08abe47c53ac8b5c/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L2307-L2311))

> This sample loads JSON and then queries values from it using SelectToken(String) with a JSONPath query.

Which is using `JObject.SelectToken` (inherited from `JToken`)

from [Querying JSON with JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)

Comment: Newtonsoft is talking about the same thing.  The original article is [# JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).  In the context of [tag:json.net], the correct stackoverflow tag is [tag:jsonpath].   There might be some contexts other than Json.NET in which a [tag:jpath] might be correct, for instance https://github.com/stsvilik/jPath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dived into this and found the issue.

- In the namespace 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonPath' there is also a class `JPath`, which is the implementation of the JSON expression. It's probably not called JsonPath as it will be an issue with the namespace.

So, the `JPath` is the implementing class for JSON Path and thus there are the same.

Update: created a [PR for improving the documentation](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/2175) - and it's merged! :)