# Parse json from web request response

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest, javascriptserializer

Im trying to parse a http web response into an array or something so i can work with the information. This is the json response i get (+ a lot more, but i just censored the format):

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": 200
    },
    "data": {
        "account": {
            "account_phone_number": "XXXXXXXX",
            "account_email": "MAIL@hotmail.com"
        },
        "user": {
            "id": "5f2b17e7836fc7010025aed3",
            "age": 23,
        }
    }
}
```

How can i write the "id" inside of "user" to console or a textbox?

This is my web request:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "url_here";
    try
    {
        var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("x-auth-token", "Auth_token");

            using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                {
                    var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(jsonResponse);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("No workie");
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
public class Test
{
   public string meta {get;set;}
   public string data {get;set;}
}
```

and trying to serialize the json into a table as following:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Test[] Tester = js.Deserialize<Test[]>(jsonResponse);
richTextBox1.AppendText(Tester);
```

But no luck. Can anyone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: You go to http://quicktype.io and paste your json in there.. It makes classes for you to represent the json and even shows you (in code comments) how to use them. The end

Comment: @Asphaug Do you need all of the information from the response or only just the `id` of the `user` object?

Comment: @PeterCsala I know what tags i need, for an example i need both the ```id``` and ```age``` inside ```user```. AND only the ```account_email``` from ```account```.

Comment: @Asphaug Can you use different serializer than `JavaScriptSerializer`? Or is it a constraint that you have to satisfy?

Comment: @PeterCsala I guess i can do it any way that works. This is just the solution i thought was right.

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` isn't recommended to use anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use other serializer than `JavaScriptSerializer` then you can take advantage of partial deserializing.

In case of [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (formerly known as Newtonsoft Json) you have at least two options:

### `SelectToken`

```cs
JObject semiParsedData = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
string id = (string)semiParsedData.SelectToken("data.user.id");
int age = (int)semiaParsedData.SelectToken("data.user.age");
string email = (string)semiParsedData.SelectToken("data.account.account_email");
```

- By calling the `Parse` method we will have a semi-parsed object.
- On this object we can issue a [Json Path query](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) via the [SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken_1.htm).

  - The syntax is similar to XPath, which can be used to retrieve any
    arbitrary data form an XML.
  - More precisely it is a [JPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981643/is-jpath-the-same-as-jsonpath-in-json-net).
- `SelectToken` returns a `JToken`. From it you can retrieve data in several ways:

  - `(string)semiParsedData.SelectToken("data.user.id")`
  - `semiParsedData.SelectToken("data.user.id").Value<string>()`
  - `semiParsedData.SelectToken("data.user.id").ToObject<string>()`

References:

- [JObject.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)
- [JObject's SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm)

### `indexer operator`

```cs
JObject semiParsedData = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
JToken data = semiParsedData["data"];

JToken user = data["user"];
string id = (string)user["id"];
int age = (int)user["age"];

JToken account = data["account"];
string email = (string)account["account_email"];
```

- `JToken` defines the following indexer operator, which is not really useful:

```cs
public virtual JToken? this[object key]
{
    get => throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot access child value on {0}.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, GetType()));
    set => throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot set child value on {0}.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, GetType()));
}
```

- On the other hand its derived class `JObject` overrides this to make that functionality useful:

  - (`JObject` derives from `JContainer`, which derives from `JToken`).

```cs
public JToken? this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(propertyName, nameof(propertyName));
        JProperty? property = Property(propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        return property?.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        JProperty? property = Property(propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.Value = value!;
        }
        else
        {
#if HAVE_INOTIFY_PROPERTY_CHANGING
            OnPropertyChanging(propertyName);
#endif
            Add(propertyName, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

- Here the `Property` method tries to get the requested entity from the `_properties` collection:

  - `private readonly JPropertyKeyedCollection _properties`

Reference:

- [JToken indexer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Comment: I may be a completely noob right now, but ```Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll```.

```using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
{
    var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();

    JObject semiParsedData = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
    JToken data = semiParsedData["data"];

    JToken user = data["user"];
    string id = (string)user["id"];
    int age = (int)user["age"];

    JToken account = data["account"];
    string email = (string)account["account_email"];

    Console.WriteLine(id);
}```

Comment: @Asphaug Could you please debug it to know which line of the above code piece throws the `ArgumentNullException`?

Comment: ```int age = (int)user["age"];``` ```System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Arg_ParamName_Name'```

Comment: Damn, i misspelled something after censoring it back to the correct format. This actually worked! Now i need to understand whats going on :o Thank you!

Comment: @Asphaug I'm glad that it works. If you wish I can extend my proposed solution with some explanation.

Comment: @Asphaug I've extended my answer please check it if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is Correct except your **Test** Class

For Complex JSON use https://json2csharp.com/ For Converting Json To C# Class

```
public class Meta    {
    public int status { get; set; } 
}

public class Account    {
    public string account_phone_number { get; set; } 
    public string account_email { get; set; } 
}

public class User    {
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public int age { get; set; } 
}

public class Data    {
    public Account account { get; set; } 
    public User user { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public Meta meta { get; set; } 
    public Data data { get; set; } 
}
```

and Then Use This

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var Root = js.Deserialize<Root>(jsonResponse);
```